# Where is the Android Project View in IDEA Ultimate?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

I have been using android stuido for quite some time now, and got quite attached to the compact project view that it provided (see picture below)

[image: project view in android studio]

Now I switched to Intellij IDEA ultimate, but it seems that the project view I liked so much is missing? (again, see picture below)

[image]

Is there a way to add the android studio project view to IDEA ultimate? Or am I just missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haleluya!  It was just added in Intellij 2017.2 EAP build #IU-172.2656.10. Here it is in action:

[image]

Here's the Intellij issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132639
And the Android issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37011213 And finally, the EAP download: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/

Comment: Good to know. The question that now remains is whether IDEA now is a full replacement for Android Studio, or if there are still some differences, that force developers to continue using multiple IDEs?

Comment: Well, Intellij is always going to be behind Android Studio and vice versa so it's a balance: do you want the latest Android specific tools or IDE tools?

I just keep a copy of both AS Canary and Intellij EAP so I can pop into AS for Android specific tools like the new adaptive icon generator, but I write all my code inside Intellij.

Answer (score 6):

This issue has already been filed as a bug to Android Tools team and seems to get fixed "someday".
See the bugtracker issue:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=80000

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, "Android" project view is the project view which was made by Google engineers specifically [for Android Studio](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio084released) and wasn't merged into the Intellij platform. So no, there is no way you can enable it in the Intellij Idea (not that I know of).

Comment: is there maybe a plugin that does something similar?

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin I've looked through the list of plugins available for installation and didn't find anything similar. by the way, you can have two IDEs - Android Studio for Android development and Intellij for other projects (of course if you don't have some limitations which don't allow you to use anything apart from Intellij).